# Clearing Stage of as2 Photo Gallery

Tags: actionscript, web, gallery, photo, movieclip

I'm building a website with several pages on different layers/frames in the timeline. On the "photos" layer, I wrote some code to a load a photo gallery. The problem is that the gallery doesn't disappear when I click on another page and keeps lingering over all the other content. Here is my code. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;

this.createEmptyMovieClip("container",1);
var imagesNumber:Number = 9;
var scrolling:Boolean = true;

for (i=1; i<=imagesNumber; i++) {
container.attachMovie("thumb"+i,"thumb"+i+"_mc",i);
myThumb_mc = container["thumb"+i+"_mc"];
myThumb_mc._x = (i-1)*myThumb_mc._width;
myThumb_mc._y = (Stage.height-myThumb_mc._height)/2;
myThumb_mc._alpha = 50;
myThumb_mc.largerImage = i;
myThumb_mc.onRollOver = function() {
    this._alpha = 100;
};
myThumb_mc.onRollOut = function() {
    this._alpha = 50;
};
myThumb_mc.onRelease = function() {
    this._alpha=50;
    for (i=1; i<=imagesNumber; i++) {
        var myClip = container["thumb"+i+"_mc"];
        myClip.enabled = false;
    }
    scrolling = false;
    _root.attachMovie("image"+this.largerImage,"large_mc",2);
    large_mc._x = (Stage.width-large_mc._width)/2;
    large_mc._y = (Stage.height-large_mc._height)/2;
    new Tween(large_mc, "_alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 100, 0.5, true);
    new Tween(container, "_alpha", Strong.easeOut, 100, 50, 0.5, true);
    large_mc.onRelease = function() {
        this.enabled=false;
        scrolling = true;
        var myFadeOut = new Tween(large_mc, "_alpha", Strong.easeOut, 100, 0, 0.5, true);
        new Tween(container, "_alpha", Strong.easeOut, 50, 100, 0.5, true);
        myFadeOut.onMotionFinished = function() {
            for (i=1; i<=imagesNumber; i++) {
                var myClip = container["thumb"+i+"_mc"];
                myClip.enabled = true;
            }
            large_mc.removeMovieClip();
        };
    };
};
}
container.onEnterFrame = function() {
if (scrolling) {
    this._x += Math.cos((-_root._xmouse/Stage.width)*Math.PI)*15;
    if (this._x>0) {
        this._x = 0;
    }
    if (-this._x>(this._width-Stage.width)) {
        this._x = -(this._width-Stage.width);
}
    }
};
```